# adding approval process in github action workflow and send notification mail to approver

Tags: github-actions

I have created a github action workflow to deploy code but now i need to add the approval functionality before deploying, once build is done approver should get a mail notification to approve the deployment, how can i achieve this?

below is my workflow file :

```
name: DEV Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '1.8'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install

    - name: Unit Testing
      run: echo "Hello World!"
    - name: Deploy 
      run: echo "Hi World!"

  Deploy-dev:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '1.8'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install
    - name: Deploy 
      run: echo "Hi World!"

  unit-testing:
    needs: Deploy-dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '1.8'
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: maven

    - name: Unit Testing
      run: echo "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 2):

On Github Actions you can use [Environments to set required approvers](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments) (this will send emails to the users when needed).

You can list multiple teams / people that can approve the job, and only 1 person needs to approve it from that list for the workflow to continue, [as explained to this other section of the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#required-reviewers):

> Use required reviewers to require a specific person or team to approve workflow jobs that reference the environment. You can list up to six users or teams as reviewers. The reviewers must have at least read access to the repository. **Only one of the required reviewers needs to approve the job for it to proceed.**

If you don't want to use this solution, a workaround could be to use this [manual-approval action](https://trstringer.com/github-actions-manual-approval/), which also allows you to inform more than 1 approver.

Comment: thanks for the help but as per the link while i try it shows : Error: Unable to resolve action Niladri579/github-actions-example@v2, unable to find version, even if i try with other v. number also its not working , what this "@v" stands for

Comment: This `@ref` refers to a tag, branch or commit from the github action repository. The repo you shared doesn't seem to exist on github `https://github.com/Niladri579/github-actions-example`, as the name states, I guess it was only an example.